# Javascript member function call within another member function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider this javascript:

```
let m = {
  add: (a,b) => a+b,
  subtract: (a,b) => a-b,
  doit: () => console.log(this.add(5,4)),
};

m.doit();
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
  doit: () => console.log(this.add(5,4)),
                               ^
TypeError: this.add is not a function
```

What is the proper way to call the `add` function from within `doit`?

Comment: **Arrow function** don't bind `this`. A regular function: `doit: function () { console.log(this.add(5,4)); }` should work.

Comment: the this argument inside of arrow functions is bound to the this of the enclosing type. In the above code you could ether replace your functions with full "function" functions. Or you could reference "m" instead of "this"

Comment: Another way of solving the problem would be to use `m` instead of `this`: `doit: () => console.log( m.add(5,4) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions use `this` from outer scope but not the object they are called with.

Try this:

```
let m = {
  add: function(a,b) { return a+b; },
  doit: function() { console.log(this.add(5,4)); }
};
```

Yet, why not to use classes in this case?

Comment: No need to change `add` as it does't use `this`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Technically true, but for uniformity...

Comment: Agree but it kind of create confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function allows to use lexical `this`, which is not `m` object but a context where `m` was defined.

The proper short syntax for object literal method is:

```
let m = {
  add: (a,b) => a+b,
  subtract: (a,b) => a-b,
  doit() {
    console.log(this.add(5,4));
  }
};
```